# A question from real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A$ and $B$ be two non empty sets of real numbers such that $A \cup B  =  (0,1)$ then this implies that $ \inf(A)\inf(B) = 0 $ and if the claim is not true then give an example to support your answer! 
My approach was to prove by contradiction by assuming that $\inf(A)= a$ and $\inf (B)=b$ where both are greater than zero. So as the interval is uncountable  if both were to be non zero then elements from $(0,a)$ would be missing from the union if $b \gt a \gt 0$ as $\inf(A \cup B) = \min(\inf(A),\inf(B))$ which contradicts the fact that $\inf(A \cup B)=0$

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: Fully correct or partially sir ? Coz i still think something can be improved to make it sound more simpler

Comment: But is it not overelaborate? I mean, you have assumed that $\inf(A \cup B) = \min(\inf A, \inf B)$, which is enough to finish the question : since $\inf A \cup B  = 0$, the minimum of $\inf A$ and $\inf B$ is $0$, so one of them is zero, so their product is zero.

Comment: For any non-empty $A,B\subset \Bbb R$ that have lower bounds in $\Bbb R $ we have $\min (\inf A, \inf B)=\inf (A\cup B).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is good, but you're too fast.

Let $a=\inf A$ and $b=\inf B$. Let $c=\min(a,b)/2$. If $c>0$, then either $c\in A$ or $c\in B$; on the other hand, $0<c<a$ implies $c\notin A$ and $0<c<b$ implies $c\notin B$. Therefore $c=0$, so $\min(a,b)=0$.

Comment: But that would be the proof for the already known result ( I use it too often that I just remember it now)

Comment: Though your proof is good ! I like it's concise form thanks !! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Note $\{1/n:n\ge 2\}\subset A \cup B.$ Thus either $A$ or $B$ contains $1/n$ for infinitely many $n.$ WLOG $A$ does. Then no positive number can be a lower bound for $A.$ Thus $\inf A \le 0.$ But $A\subset (0,1),$ so $0$ is a lower bound for $A,$ giving $\inf A \ge 0.$ It follows that $\inf A =0,$ proving the result.